# How to dereference this array? And how do I store this array into a hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, hashmap, dereference

I'm having some trouble getting around Perl's referencing and dereferencing, I'm coming from a C++ background, so I understand dereferencing and referencing. It's just that Perl's syntax has got me thrown for a tizzy.

I have this code where I'm trying to print the contents of `$obj->{numbers}`

```
my @arr = (1,2,3,4,5,6);

my $test = "" . join(',', @arr). "" || '';

my @my_arr = ();

@my_arr = split (',', $test);

my $obj->{numbers} = \@my_arr;

print $obj->{numbers};
```

This will print
`ARRAY(0x1ac9af8)`.

I'm expecting it to print something out like
`1 2 3 4 5 6`.

Also I want to store this array in a hash like so

```
my $this;
$this->{foo} = [ { bar => $obj->{numbers} } ];
print $this->{foo}[0];
```

This prints `HASH(0x418b018)`. I also want this to print `1 2 3 4 5 6`.

How would I be able to print this array within the hash?

Comment: To serialise Perl data structures, take a look at [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$obj->{numbers}` returns a reference to an array, which is why you see something like `ARRAY(0x1ac9af8)` when you print it.

You can dereference the array using `@{ }`.  For example:

```
print "@{ $obj->{numbers} }";
```

prints:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I used [double quotes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%22) so that you would get a single space between each element of the array.

Similarly for the array in the hash:

```
print "@{ $this->{foo}[0]{bar} }";
```

See also [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc)